# Show that the sequence defined recursively by $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3a_n + 1}$ is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> Assume that the sequence ${a_n}$ is defined recursively by $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3a_n + 1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, with $a_1 = 1$. Use mathematical induction to prove that $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

I've gotten most of the way, but I need help with the last bit. I've proven the base case, and gotten as far as:

Assume $P(k)$ is true. That is, $a_k \leq a_{k+1}$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$.
Prove $P(k+1)$. That is, $a_{k+1} \leq a_{k+1+1}$.

And now I'm stuck.

Comment: Try substituting in the definition of $a_n$ into both your "assume" and "to prove" statements.

Comment: Okay I think I have got it but i just want to be sure im doing it right. For the "to prove" statement, I did sqrt(3a(n)+1) <= sqrt(3*sqrt(3a(n)+1)+1).
Then i squared both sides and substituted 1 for a(n) and got the desired inequality. Is this correct?

Comment: Why would you substitute 1 for $a_n$?  $a_n=1$ only for $n=0$.

Comment: Okay well is the rest of it correct then? Just keeping a(n) arbitrary and solving the inequality?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "solving the inequality". It would help if you post your work.  But you need to be careful that you don't accidentally *assume* the conclusion that you are trying to prove.  It sounds like you have managed to derive the assumption $P(k)$ from the conclusion $P(k+1)$.  If so, then you need to check that the steps of that derivation are all reversible.  If they are, then you have a proof that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$.

Comment: Okay. Here we go (I apologize for my lack of formatting; I'm new to this).
so a(n+1) = sqrt(3a(n) + 1).
Does this mean that a(n+2) = sqrt(3a(n+1) + 1) = 
sqrt(3 * sqrt(3(an) + 1) + 1)

and then to reduce you square both sides to get:
3a(n) + 1 <= 3*sqrt(3a(n) + 1) + 1?

Comment: Try it this way:  Start by writing down $a_{k} < a_{k+1}$.  That's your induction hypothesis; you are allowed to assume it's true.  Now can you find some way to manipulate that inequality until it says $\sqrt{3a_k +1} < \sqrt{3a_{k+1} + 1}$?  If you can manage that, you are just a step away from the conclusion you want.

Comment: Woah. That makes so much sense now. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 4):

$a_{n+1} - a_n = \sqrt{3a_n+1} - \sqrt{3a_{n-1}+1} = \dfrac{3(a_n-a_{n-1})}{\sqrt{3a_n+1}+\sqrt{3a_{n-1}+1}} \geq 0$ since by the inductive step: $a_n \geq a_{n-1}$, and the proof is completed.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ where $f$ is an increasing function, the resulting sequence is monotone. Indeed, whichever inequality you have between $a_1$ and $a_2$ will propagate to subsequent terms:

$$a_{k+1}\ge a_k \implies f(a_{k+1})\ge f(a_k)$$
or 
$$a_{k+1}\le a_k \implies f(a_{k+1})\le f(a_k)$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a_n\geq a_{n-1}$ we have $3a_n\geq 3a_{n-1}$ and also $3a_n+1\geq 3a_{n-1}+1$. Now, since square root is a monotonic function, we get $\sqrt{3a_n+1}\geq\sqrt{3a_{n-1}+1}$. Eventually:
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3a_n+1}\geq\sqrt{3a_{n-1}+1}=a_{n} $$