# Let $a_1=1$, for each $n\geq 1$ let $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3+2a_n}$. Prove with induction that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\leq 3.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let $a_1=1$ and for each $n\geq 1$ let $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3+2a_n}$. Prove with induction that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $$a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\leq 3.$$

---

For the base case $n=1$, I already know it works. Assume $n=k$ works: $a_k\leq a_{k+1}\leq 3$. However, I'm having trouble proving that $a_{k+1}\leq a_{k+2}\leq 3.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution verification: Prove by induction that $a_1 = \sqrt{2} , a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_n} $ is increasing and bounded by $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243378/solution-verification-prove-by-induction-that-a-1-sqrt2-a-n1-sqrt). It works the same way for your question.

Comment: Also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265559/show-that-the-sequence-defined-recursively-by-a-n1-sqrt3a-n-1-is-inc?rq=1).